# NSTreeController binding doesn't update NSUserDefaultsController for sub-items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I have an NSTreeController that's bound to an NSUserDefaultsController through the Xcode interface builder. When I add an item to the root tree content through the tree controller's `addObject:` method, it updates and saves to the defaults controller and everything works perfectly.

When I add a child to any of the tree controller's root objects, however, the tree controller updates (and updates the outline view that's also bound to it) but does *not* save to user defaults. I'm modifying the objects through the keypath specified in the tree controller, and in a KVC-complient way:

```
[[[self.userFeedsController.content objectAtIndex:0]
    mutableArrayValueForKey:@"children"] addObject:
        [[ATLUserFeedFolder alloc] initWithLabel:@"Bindings are stupidly complicated"]
];
```

My settings:

[image: The NSTreeController settings]

[image: The NSTreeController bindings]

[image: The NSUserDefaults settings]

How can I modify root-items' children in a way that will ensure they're saved to user defaults?

Comment: It's only used if you let the tree controller create objects but Entity Mode is for use with Core Data. What happens when you add a child through the tree controllers `insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndexPath:`?

Comment: The NSUserDefaultsController is, I think, basically architected to do KVO on immutable objects.  It doesn't know the children of your root objects has changed if you're not replacing the entire root object with a new one.  KVO isn't "deep" -- if you have an entire tree of NSTreeNodes, and you using KVO to monitor changes to the root node, you can add and remove many things without KVO firing.

Comment: @Willeke The same thing happens. I also tried with "Class Mode" and it had the same effect.

Comment: @stevesliva Is there any way I can manually tell KVO to fire? I've tried `[self.userFeedsController didChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];` and `[self.userFeedsController.arrangedObjects didChangeValueForKey:@"childNodes"];` and `[self.userFeedsController.arrangedObjects.childNodes[0] didChangeValueForKey:@"childNodes"];` so far.

Comment: You're saving `childNodes` -- is this an NSArray of NSTreeNode objects?  Do you really want to stuff `[childNodes valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.representedObject"]` in there instead?  That is to say, I'm lost in the details here.  But what I might suggest is that if you want the children to trigger KVO on the parent, just have the methods that mutate the child modify the childrenKeyPath in the parent object.  ie, the ugly `[self.parent setChildren:self.parent.children]`